# How to assign internal table into a structure and then to a field in ABAP

Tags: abap

With the below code I can retrieve the content of the internal table `t_t005e`, however when put into the field `wa_upload-region`, only the first column of the data is retrieved, however I want to retrieve the third column data.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_upload,
  " ...
  region TYPE regio,
  " ...
END OF ty_upload.

DATA: wa_upload TYPE ty_upload,
      t_t005e   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t005e.

READ TABLE t_t005e
           INTO wa_upload-region
           WITH KEY land1 = 'GB'
                    regio = 'YK'
                    counc = ''.
```

As a result, I have created a work area `wa_t005e`, with the same type as the lines of `t_t005e`.

I want to first read the internal table `t_t005e` into the work area `wa_t005e`, then to the field `wa_upload-region`.

Following is my work in progress:

```
    DATA: wa_t005e TYPE t005e.

    LOOP AT t_t005e INTO wa_t005e.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT wa_t005e-regio OF STRUCTURE 
          wa_t005e TO <wa_upload-region>.
    ENDLOOP.
```

How to get the data of `wa_t005e-regio` into the field `wa_upload-region`?

Comment: Should I tell you that the answer is as simple as `w_upload-region = w_t005e-regio.` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of reading **the value of only one column from a table directly into one field of a structure**, at least in systems pre-7.40. If you do have a 7.40 system, you can use a ["table expression"](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentable_expressions.htm) like this:

```
TRY.
    wa_upload-region = t_t005e[ land1 = 'GB' regio = 'YK' counc = '' ]-regio.
  CATCH cx_sy_itab_line_not_found.
ENDTRY.
```

In older system, you will have to read the whole table line into a [structure](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendata_objects_structure.htm), then you can just take the field from it, like this:

```
READ TABLE t_t005e INTO wa_t005e WITH KEY land1 = 'GB' regio = 'YK' counc = ''.
wa_upload-region = wa_t005e-regio.
```

If you want to use [ASSIGN](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapassign.htm) and the like, you can do that too. First you would read the table line into a structure again (in this case a [field symbol](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_field_symbols.htm) to stay in theme). Then assign the needed component/field of the structure to a single-value field symbol.

```
DATA: t_upload TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_upload,
      t_t005e TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t005e.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_upload> TYPE ty_upload,
               <fs_t005e>  TYPE t005e,
               <region>    TYPE regio.   " or type any

SELECT *
  FROM t005e
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE t_t005e.

READ TABLE t_t005e ASSIGNING <fs_t005e> WITH KEY land1 = 'GB' regio = 'YK' counc = ''.
ASSIGN COMPONENT 'REGIO' OF STRUCTURE <fs_t005e> TO <region>.   " <---
*Other option: number of column
*ASSIGN COMPONENT 3 OF STRUCTURE <fs_t005e> TO <region>.

APPEND INITIAL LINE TO t_upload ASSIGNING <fs_upload>.
<fs_upload>-region = <region>.

WRITE <fs_upload>-region.
```

But is reading only one entry from the table really what you want to do? You didn't specify all keys of `t005e` in the READ statement. It would only select the first line that fits.